# Does helium have any accidental degeneracies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, atomic-physics

Does helium have any accidental degeneracies, i.e. are there reducible eigenspaces of $$-\Delta_1 - \Delta_2 - \frac{2}{r_1} - \frac{2}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_{12}}~?$$

Comment: What do you mean by "reducible eigenspace"?

Comment: The group of symmetries preserves each eigenspace of the operator. The eigenspace is irreducible iff no proper subspace of the eigenspace is preserved by the group of symmetries.

Comment: Oh, you mean reducible representations of the global symmetry group - that's important to specify.

Comment: I'm curious what else it could refer to. I'm new to this topic. Is there another situation to which "accidental degeneracy" could refer?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. Nor does hydrogen, for that matter. Accidental degeneracies essentially never occur in natural systems with a finite number of particles.

Essentially all nontrivial degeneracies in non-contrived quantum systems are the result of symmetries; i.e. if two energy eigenstates $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are degenerate, then they are related by $|\phi\rangle = U |\psi\rangle$ for some unitary representation $U$ of a symmetry operator that commutes with the Hamiltonian. While this is somewhat a question of terminology, I would say that such a degeneracy is "symmetry-induced" rather than "accidental".

An example of an accidental symmetry would be a particle in a 2D box with aspect ratio $L_y/L_x = \sqrt{3/5}$. The $(n_x = 3, n_y = 1)$ and $(n_x = n_y = 2)$ energy eigenstates both happen to have energy
$E_{3,1} = E_{2,2} = 16 \pi^2 \hbar^2/(3 L_x^2)$, so they are accidentally degenerate, but there is no global symmetry of the Hamiltonian that maps either state to the other. Like all accidental degeneracies, this one is fine-tuned and immediately vanishes if we slightly perturb the Hamiltonian, and it has no connection to any conserved quantities. Such arbitrarily fine-tuned conditions rarely occur in nature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there an explanation? One can not determine the eigenspaces analytically. Is the answer based on experimental evidence? Or is the answer based on intuition that comes from perturbation theory.

Comment: What about the degeneracy in hydrogen for states of given $n$ but different $l$? That can be mathematically treated in terms of a hidden symmetry (there is an extra constant of the motion which is a special case for $1/r$ potential).

Comment: @AndrewSteane I've expanded my answer to give more detail. To some degree this is a matter of definitions, but I would say that the degeneracy of the hydrogen atom is definitely *not* accidental, but is instead a result of the hydrogen atom's non-obvious but important $SO(4)$ symmetry, which has important consequences even in the classical case (like the conservation of the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector that you mentioned).

Comment: @ChrisJudge Are you talking about accidental *symmetries* or accidental *degeneracies*? "Accidental degeneracy" is a fairly straightforward concept that applies in nonrelativistic QM (which I discuss in my answer), while "accidental *symmetry*" is a much more subtle concept involving renormalization in quantum field theories, which I believe is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: @tparker I don't see how your answer addresses the case of helium. How do you know there are no degeneracies?

Comment: @ChrisJudge My answer applies to all systems that are not artificially fine-tuned. Helium is no different from any other system in that respect.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but to be really pedantic, any degeneracy can be "explained" by a symmetry operator $U$, in the sense that if $|0\rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$ are degenerate, you can just define $U|0 \rangle = |1 \rangle$, $U|1 \rangle = - |0 \rangle$, and $U$ acts trivially on all other states. The nontrivial part of symmetries is that often $U$ is generated by some simple physical quantity we already care about for some other reason.

Comment: @tparker What does `artificially fine tuned' mean?  To say something is rare in nature, does not mean something does not happen.

Comment: @ChrisJudge That's a complicated question, which I think would require a separate Physics SE post to address.

Comment: @knzhou That's an excellent point. I wonder if there's some precise and general way to distinguish "physically interesting" symmetry operators from "artificial" ones. Perhaps physically interesting symmetry operators should be representations of the Poincare group? Or perhaps they should commute with not just a single Hamiltonian with fixed coupling constants, but with a whole family of Hamiltonians of a given functional form with generic coupling constants?

Comment: I think the field to go to answer that question would be integrable systems, which are defined to have “a very large number of conserved quantities”. I’ve always been confused what that means, since any system has arbitrarily many contrived conserved quantities, but presumably they have some criterion. I think it might have to do with having a simple functional form in terms of the phase space variables.

Comment: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1984.0022

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least helium ion He$^+$ has the same accidental degeneracy as the hydrogen atom (although the degeneracy is only exact in the nonrelativistic limit for both of them).

EDIT (September 21, 2022): The above can also be adapted to the neutral He atom as follows. Let us consider the states of the neutral He where one of the electrons is in a highly excited state (still bound, but close to a free state). As this electron can be pretty far from the nucleus, it will not influence the state of the other electron much, so such states of the neutral He will be somewhat [similar to the states of the hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_state):

> In general, at sufficiently high principal quantum numbers, an excited
> electron - ionic core system will have the general character of a
> hydrogenic system and the energy levels will follow the Rydberg
> formula.

Furthermore, let us consider two almost degenerate states of the He$^+$ ion and add to each of them an electron in a "high" Rydberg state. As the spectrum of "high" Rydberg states is pretty dense, one can probably choose the states of the Rydberg electrons in such a way that the difference in their energies would compensate the inaccuracy of the degeneracy. Let me also add that spectral lines (and all energy levels except for the ground level) have natural width, which can simplify finding degeneracy. So it looks like one can find states of the neutral He atom that are closer to degeneracy than any states of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: The OP’s Hamiltonian refers to neutral helium with two electrons.

Comment: @tparker : Not really. Their Hamiltonian can also describe a He$^+$ ion and a remote electron.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, because in that case the spectrum is completely different, since it's the sum of a hydrogen atom spectrum plus a nearly free particle spectrum. (E.g. it's continuous for all energies above the GS energy, rather than having a band where the spectrum is purely discrete.) Also, in order to enforce that limiting case, you'd need to modify the Hilbert space to enforce that one electron cannot get close to the nucleus, which would in turn change the energy spectrum.

Comment: @tparker : I cannot agree with you. The Hamiltonian is exactly the same, so the spectrum is exactly the same, and the Hilbert space is exactly the same. I simply consider a specific part of the spectrum.

Comment: A Hamiltonian's spectrum is a multiset of real numbers. What do you mean by "a specific part of the spectrum"? Do you mean the intersection of the spectrum with some real interval $(a, b)$? I don't understand how a specific *physical* limit corresponds to "a specific part" of the spectrum. For any multisets $S \subset T \subset \mathbb{R}$, you can say that "$S$ is exactly equal to a specific part of $T$", but that statement seems pretty trivial physically.

Comment: @tparker: So states containing a He$^+$ ion and a remote electron have certain energies, and such energies make only a part of the total spectrum of the Hamiltonian. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: Because that observation is totally trivial. Under that definition, *every* quantum system's spectrum is just "a part of" the spectrum of a single free particle (potentially after shifting by a global constant). I don't see what physical insight is gained from that observation.

Comment: @tparker : There will still be strong lines related to transitions within the ion.

Comment: @akhmeteli I am not interested in He+.

Comment: @ChrisJudge : No problem, please see EDIT to my answer.

Comment: @akhmeteli  As tparker indicated above, I am looking for exact spectrum not approximation.

Comment: The final paragraph won't work. Helium does not have stable doubly-excited states. Everything from $2s^2$ and $2s2p$ upwards is higher in energy than the first ionization threshold, so the states become autoionizing resonances in the continuum.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : I don't quite understand that. Hydrogen states 1s and 1p are (almost) degenerate, and similar He states 1s30s and 1p30s are probably also almost degenerate and immune to autoionization, as their "low" electrons probably cannot lose any energy. Moreover, even if some states in question autoionize, they are not much different in principle from most other states, as, if I am not mistaken, there are no stable states anyway (except for ground states).

Comment: @akhmeteli There is no such thing as $1p30s$ because there is no such thing as $1p$. If you want hydrogenic (quasi)degeneracies, then you're looking at least at $2s$-to-$2p$, and, as mentioned, any additional excitation on top of that will bring the state over the ionization threshold. If you have particular states in mind that will not autoionize, by all means mention them (I could be missing something), but hand-waving is not enough there.

Comment: As far as the last comment ("they are not much different in principle from most other states"), I strongly disagree. Of course all states will decay radiatively to the ground state *when* (*if*) coupled to the EM field. But OP is pitched explicitly as the electrostatic hamiltonian. And if you're OK with autoionization, you might as well ignore bound states altogether and find degeneracies in two different continua, but that is clearly not what OP is asking for.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : Sorry for the error with 1p. And yes, technically, the OP's Hamiltonian does not describe spontaneous emission, but then, equally technically, degeneracy of autoionizing states is still degeneracy. One can argue whether this is as trivial as degeneracy of continuum. I tend to say no, as I suspect some of such states may have relatively long lifetime.

Comment: @akhmeteli The autoionizing states are not physical. They are Fano resonances in the continuum; it then becomes a structured continuum, but it's a continuum nonetheless. As far as degeneracy is concerned there's no difference to an unstructured continuum, particularly since OP is very clear that they're uninterested in lifetime considerations.

Comment: @Why are autoionizing states not physical? If the atom is initially in this state (say, as a result of excitation by electrons), it will stay in this state for some time. If autoionizing states are not physical, then no states are physical, except for ground states. And I can see that OP is not interested in states above the ionization level, but I can see it in OP's comments, not in the question.